# Laravel access variables in template from child section

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3.

I have an email template like that :

```
<?php 
$styles = 'margin: auto;' ?>

<!-- Main -->
@yield('main')
....
```

Is there a way to access the $styles variable from a child ?

```
@extends('emails.template')

@section('main')
    <p style="{{ $styles }}">Lorem Ipsum.</p>
@section
```

I got a undefined error, maybe I use the wrong approach ?

Comment: I think yield is not made for that. You may should use include.

Comment: Yes but this is a template, I can't use include because the view to include changes for each controller.

Comment: Maybe take a look into the compiled template. Maybe that gives you a hint

Answer (score 0):

Try `@extends('emails.template', ['styles' => $styles])`

If it's wrong, try to pass the variable from the controller.